# Data does not show on click button in Android Mobile but working in LiveCode

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, livecode

```
on mouseUp
 local tResult
  local k
 put "http://htp2.hitecpoint.in:98/api/blackbox/live/45" into k
  put the URL k into tResult 
 set the text of field "Field" to tResult
end mouseUp
```

Hello Friends. I am working in Livecode.I have make simple program which call a Web Api and result in xml.All code work fine in Livecode framework .But when I make a (.apk)build of that program and run in my Andriod device. It installed, but then on click of button data not show.Please reply

Comment: Could it maybe be permissions?  Check if 'Internet' is enabled in the standalone settings for android.

Comment: Don't write `the` in front of `url`.

Comment: ok mark i will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I should check on  'Internet' option which provide in the standalone settings for android.Now It working.